# To open same responsive page on different platform like mobile, desktop and tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If I have to open same responsive page on different platform like mobile, desktop and tab with different control size using selenium then how can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you mean? You want to use Selenium on a tablet, mobile and desktop? Or do you just want to test the responsiveness on different window sizes?

Comment: Can you update the question with some more details about the usecase you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your query is regarding a compatibility test for a webpage on devices with different screen sizes and OS platforms. For this, you may use Appium for testing on mobile devices and TestNG for orchestrating parallel testing. Additionally, you will have to set up an array of all the test devices where you need to run tests or create emulators for those devices.

Here's an [article](https://www.guru99.com/cross-browser-testing-using-selenium.html) that explains exactly that. I would like to point out that this is a rather tedious process.

As a suggestion, another easier way without selenium is to use one of the code-less automated testing tools on the cloud that removes the hassle of setting up the test devices.